# getting values of primary key from table name

Tags: java, mysql

I have table as follow ::

```
id  || name     || Desg         || Sal  || deptId
1   ||ajay      ||MD            ||999   ||1
2   ||Kaushal   ||Engg          ||100   ||2
3   ||Vidhi     ||HR            ||5000  ||3
4   ||Sonu      ||SSP           ||200   ||1
5   ||Jay       ||Asst Manager  ||120   ||3
6   ||Uvi       ||Utra          ||450   ||5
```

id is primary column. This is just one table with name `person`. 
I want to get the values of primary key column (here id). 
My `java` method will receives the table name & where clause and will return the ArrayList of values of primary Column. Now the problem is that based on table name it should be decided which column is primary column. Is there any query which can give values  ::

`<<Part of Query to get values of primary column key>> where sal > 150 & deptId != 1` (Where clause that method will receive)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Database metadata can be extracted from the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` tables, as documented [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-schema.html).

I think the table you'd be looking at would be `columns`:

```
SELECT    COLUMN_NAME
FROM      INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE     TABLE_SCHEMA = '<<your schema name>>'
  AND     TABLE_NAME = '<<your table name>>'
  AND     COLUMN_KEY = 'PRI'
```

although that's only for a simplistic case.

For proper index analysis, the [`statistics`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/statistics-table.html) table can be consulted. From (somewhat vague) memory, the index name or type can be used to figure out if the index is a primary key index.

Once you *have* the primary key column name, you can simply construct another query based on that.

In other words (untested):

```
String prim_colm = getPrimaryKeyColumn (tableName);
String newQuery = "select " + prim_colm + " from " + tableName";
```

then execute `newQuery`.

Comment: In this way I am getting the name of Primary key column. i.e. 'id'. But I want to get the values of that column ...like 1,2,3.4...So is there a query through which on the fly it can be decided which is the primary key of given table & fetch only those column/columns from DB ? and yes the query above takes much time when i run for first time....thanks for help....

Comment: @hemu, I've added to the answer. Basically you run one query on INFORMATION_SCHEMA to get the primary column name, then build another query on the actual table, using that column name.

Comment: Yes..that will definitely work. But for that we will need to make 2 database call. One to get primary Key column name (from getPrimaryKeyColumn method) and another to get values of that column. I wonder if we can get values all in one call ...

Comment: No, not to my knowledge. Even a join won't work because joining is for between _data items,_ not a data item and a column name.

Comment: K..No problem...I edited ur answer....and used dynamic SQL...May be it will work...I will try through java..

Answer (score -2):

To answer the second part of your question

```
<<Part of Query to get values of primary column key>>
```

use...

```
SELECT <column name> FROM <table name> WHERE....
```

Where <column name>/<table name> comes from where ever you decide to work it out. Querying database meta data or just using a switch.

Comment: Fair enough. Question wasn't particularly clear though, I was just answering the bit of the question he repeated.